# Remove and insert to specific position of string in php

Tags: c#, php, string

Hi guys this is the `C#` code I want to change it to `php` code but there is no `insert` and `remove` function in `php`

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
{
     NewPlace = i * Convert.ToUInt16(st[i]);
     NewPlace = NewPlace % st.Length;
     ch = st[i];
     st = st.Remove(i, 1);
     st = st.Insert(NewPlace, ch.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried write anything by yourself? People will not write code for you here in SO.

Comment: do you have an example of the input and output or any code you have tried, there is `substr()` and `substr_replace()` just to name two functions that would work for this.  Also PHP strings can be turned into arrays with `str_split($str,1)` quite easily.

Comment: its just a coding function for a string. for example :  input: "1234abcd" output:"21cbd34a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I behave `st` as an `array` because removing has meaning in `arrays` not `strings`, then your code in `PHP` is like this:

```
for($i=0;$i < count($st); $i++)
{
    $NewPlace = $i * intval($st[$i]);
    $NewPlace = $NewPlace % count($st);
    $ch = $st[$i];
    unset($st[$i]);
    $st[$NewPlace] = $ch;
}
$st = array_values($st);
```

in `PHP` you can remove an element of array using `unset()` 
last line came to rearrange array to fill gaps after `unset()`

Let me know if it works.

**NOTE**

if you want to use this on strings, simply add these two line before and after the above script.

```
$st = str_split($st);  //# insert before first line
$st = implode('',$st); //# insert after last line
```